# How to do nested for loops by ray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ray

the environment is  under ray 0.7.5 python 3.7.3
I want to accelerate a 2 stages for loop like

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(20):
        ans[i][j] = function(A[i], B[j])
```

I know  for loop is something like:

```
result_ids = []
@ray.remote
def function(x):

for i in range(4):
    result_ids.append(f.remote(i))
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```